# char/varchar - длина в байтах или символах?

Tags: mysql, sql, производительность, char

На какой-то борде прочитал, что `*char` отличается от `*text` тем, что первый измеряет длину *в символах*, а второй в байтах. То есть, по логике, `char(255)` запишет строку кириллицей в *юникоде* все 255 знаков, а `text(255)` должен ее обрезать примерно до половины.

Так вот вопрос: сколько реально *байт* будет выделено под хранение фиксированного типа `char(10)` в сравнении `utf8_general_ci`? Где искать правду?

*<оффтоп> таблица разрослась до миллионов записей, запросы выполняются неприлично долго, ищу способы увеличения быстродействия. Алсо, узнал, что оказывается, если в таблице есть хотя бы одно поле переменной длины, все поля `char` автоматически преобразуются в `varchar` < /оффтоп>*

Comment: Если запросы выполняются долго, значит они не оптимизированы, возможно отсутствуют индексы. Размер самих записей влияет на общую производительность, но он не первостепенен. А в юникоде все Русские символы _всегда_ занимают два байта, они меньше в юникоде занимать физически не могут

Comment: С индексами разобрался в первую очередь и оптимизировал насколько можно (explain).

Comment: @kanaris, без должного опыта можно с натяжкой говорить *с индексами разобрался... оптимизировал насколько можно*, поэтому я бы продолжал копать в этом направлении. В частности, когда есть группировка, mysql автоматически выполняет сортировку по этой группировке, поэтому если сортировка не нужна - надо делать `order by null` Кроме `explain` будет полезно так же посмотреть и на профилирование через `set profiling = 1` и дальнейшего `show profile for query...` и т.д. И прочитайте [эту книжку](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do) (на русском только второе издание видел)

Comment: так же можно несколько улучшить производительность произведя тонкую настройку параметров конфига, про это так же можно прочитать в книге. Еще - если выполняется копирование во временную таблицу на диске, возможно, имеет смысл настроить tmpfs  для использования под эти временные таблицы и т.д.

Comment: @BOPOH спасибо, учту. Просвящаюсь по мере сталкивания с проблемами.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Символов](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html). Char, varchar, enum, text и другие ограничены длиной в символах. Но общие лимиты (например, на длину строки в таблице, или размер индекса), могут быть дополнительно сверху ограничены в байтах.

Прямым текстом сказано в [мануале](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html):

> For example, MySQL must reserve 30 bytes for a CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 column.

char(10) в utf8_general_ci займёт 30 байт вне зависимости от записанных данных.

Comment: Надо же, как я умудрился задать вопрос, на который ответ был в точности в мануале. Чорт, надо учить английский.

Answer (score 1):

Очень зависит от типа SQL, например в MySQL - длинна в символах, а в MS SQL - в байтах, вот цитата с [сайта MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Распространенное заблуждение заключается в том, чтобы думать, что с
> char(n) и varchar(n), n определяет количество символов. Однако в
> char(n) и varchar(n)n определяет длину строки в байтах (от 0 до 8
> 000). n никогда не определяет количество хранимых символов. Это
> аналогично определению nchar(n) и nvarchar(n).